# Can multiple yarn containers inside same node share disk memory?

Tags: python, apache-spark, containers, hadoop-yarn, dask

When multiple containers are allocated on one node, theoretically, since these containers are residing on the same machine, it seems like I could make them share disk memory?

More specifically, can I write some data on the disk of the machine that the containers are residing, and have each container grab that piece of data, without having to write multiple copies of the same data for each container?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. It seems you can do this by writing the file on a directory that is one level above that of the specific container you are in. I.e.
`/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1590430074619_0007` for example, in which case you would be writing to a directory that is associated with the particular application you are running.